# Zenity question - how can I use user input?

Tags: zenity

I want to make a zenity question that goes further depending on the answer you choose.

The question in my script is:

```
zenity --question --text="Would you like to participate in a little form?"
```

_

Full script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$(whoami)" != "root" ]; then
  echo "Put this is /sbin/ and chmod 755 it."
else
    zenity --info --text="Hi! Welcome to !!Name yet to be found!!"
    sleep 0.5
    zenity --question --text="Would you like to participate in a little form?" 
    sleep 1
    zenity --info --text="Getting important run files"
    wget 

    sleep 1
    zenity --info --text="Done!"
    sleep 1
    zenity --info --text="I will this program will move to /sbin/ and chmod 
775 it for you!
No need to thank me.
My program creator made me this way :(" 
    sudo chmod 755 ~/!!!
    mv ~/!!! /sbin/ 
    sleep 1
    zenity --info --text="Done!"
    sleep 2
    sudo xdg-open /sbin
    zenity --info --text="Well look for yourself!"
    sleep 10
    zenity --info --text="Dont rerun this file!"
    echo
    zenity --info --text="This is just the install part."
fi
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`zenity --question` will return the user's answer in its exit code.
You can collect it from the `$?` special variable, like so

```bsh
zenity --question --text="Are you there?"
THERE=$?
```

or use it directly in a conditional like this

```bsh
if zenity --question --text="Do you want to answer stupid questions?"
then 
    zenity --entry --text="Why?"
fi
```